# Offset queries for non-unique columns

Tags: sql, offset

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 title VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);
```

and I want to support query with offset in order to support API that would return a list of books, ordered by **non-unique** title field with a given offset and limit.

The question here is what is the most efficient way [1] to define a unique index (or helper column or anything like that) for non-unique `title` column that could be used as an opaque offset token in queries where I'm using `ORDER BY title`. I thought about an index created on function that would return a unique numeric position of a row but I'm afraid that this would severely affect timings for INSERTs and UPDATEs for big tables and I think there is an optimal solution for that.

While this is straightforward for `ORDER BY {unique_field}` queries [2] I don't see an easy way to achieve the same for non-unique fields.

Also let's assume that solution should work in postgresql and mysql.

---

Notes:

[1] Since straightforward solutions like SELECT id, title FROM book ORDER BY title OFFSET [number] LIMIT [number] work extremely bad for big numeric offset values, I would introduce some sort of opaque token that would represent an offset in a given set in my API for getting book chunks.

So API method that would return a list of books ordered by title with a given offset would look like this (pseudocode):

```
BookPage getBooks(optional string offsetToken, int limit)
```

where BookPage is defined as follows:

```
class BookPage {
 nonnull List<Book> books;
 nonnull string offsetToken; // expected to be used to return a next page
}
```

Example use, book table contains 2*N books:

```
// 1st call
BookPage page1 = getBooks(null, 2); // get first 2 books
BookPage page2 = getBooks(page1.offsetToken, 2); // get next 2 books
BookPage page3 = getBooks(page2.offsetToken, 2); // get next 2 books
//...
BookPage pageN = getBooks(pageN-1.offsetToken, 2); // get last 2 books
```

and a concatenation of lists page1.books, page2.books, ... pageN.books would produce a list of books ordered by title in ascending order.

[2] For example: If getBooks API would use offset queries where books ordered by id (which is a primary key) offsetToken would be an id of the last book and implementation of getBooks API would look as follows (pseudocode):

```
BookPage getBook(optional string offsetToken, int limit) {
 Long startId = (offsetToken != null ? toLong(offsetToken) : null);
 page.books = (SELECT id, title FROM books 
               WHERE :startId IS null OR id>:startId
               ORDER BY id
               LIMIT :limit);
 page.offsetToken = toString(lastElementOf(page.books).id)
 return page;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and simplest solution that I found so far is to use a non-unique column in conjunction with the primary key. It slightly complicates select queries - e.g. for original problem you need to write something like (title = :title AND id > :id) OR (title > :title), where :title and :id constitute offsetToken (last item's title and id).